# How to know which rails environment is running in delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a delayed job which is working perfectly fine. I want to know which environment is this. Is it production or development or staging. Check the code please. ENV["RAILS_ENV"] is nuil?

```
class SendMessageJob < Struct.new(:message_id)
  def perform
    p ENV["RAILS_ENV"] // printing nil :(
    p "hello world"

  end  
end
```

I tried including

```
require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../config/environment.rb"
```

on the top the file still nothing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `RAILS_ENV` (constant defined within Rails) or the newer one `Rails.env` (a wrapper for this).